# How to convert an HTML piece of code to a PDF file?

Tags: c#, pdf

I need to convert html to pdf, but the framework must be .net 3.5 because it runs in the context of sharepoint 2010.

I tried TuesPekin but its for .net 4.0 so I need something else.

I need the code to just take a long string of html and generate the PDF, what would u recommend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you struggle with the c# and sharepoint integration then you can do it in the client side with the [jsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) javascript library.

It's very much worth a try.

Comment: wow!, didnt even know it existed in JS, +1

Answer (score 0):

I found this library which seems free:

```
var htmlContent = String.Format("<body>Hello world: {0}</body>", 
        DateTime.Now);
var pdfBytes = (new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter()).GeneratePdf(htmlContent);
```

http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx

and it worked without any problems.